# how to echo the database contents in codeigniter while editing

Tags: codeigniter

How do i get the form field contents while editing (updating) entries in database ?

my controler is

```
//edit sidebar contents
function edit_lsidebar(){

        if(isset($_POST['heading'])){
        //adding text fields
        $heading = $this->input->post('heading');
        $content_text = $this->input->post('content_text');
        $url = $this->input->post('url');
        $link_text = $this->input->post('link_text');

        $this->Lside_bar_model->edit_lsidebar($heading, $content_text, $url, $link_text);

        redirect('welcome');
    }
    else $this->load->view('edit_lside_bar', $data);    
}
```

my model is

```
function edit_lsidebar($heading, $content_text, $url, $link_text){      
    $data = array(
    'heading'=>$heading,
    'content_text'=>$content_text,
    'url'=> $url,
    'link_text' => $link_text
    );

    $this->db->where('id',$this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->db->update('lsidebar', $data);

}
```

please help

Comment: Could you explain more what you are having problems with? I don't quite understand your question!

Comment: how to display database field contents while editing (updating record) in form fields ?

Comment: explain *more*, not repeat the same vague thing, please

Answer (score 0):

When loading your edit_lside_bar view pass the existing $heading, $content_text, $url, $link_text variables with the data array you're passing to the view.

Then inside the view echo those values as a value attribute for input fields. For example:

Inside your controller:

```
else {

$data["lside_bar"] = $this->Lside_bar_model->get_lside_bar($id); 
$this->load->view('edit_lside_bar', $data); 

}
```

Inside your view:

```
<input type="text" name="heading" value="<?php echo $lside_bar->heading; ?>" />
<textarea name="content_text"><?php echo $lside_bar->content_text; ?></textarea>
....
```

That should give you a nice push in the right direction. Hope that helps!